# Blank firefox page launched from selenium

Tags: c#

I am a new selenium user trying to launch Firefox from C# with selenium version 2.33.0
and Firefox version 20

Here is my code to launch firefox

```
var capability = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();

Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(Environment.SeleniumGridHubUrl), capability);
```

Here is my code to goto Url

```
Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Environment.Hostname[domain] + pathAndQuery);
```

The Firefox browser is launched successfully, however it is blank and does not display the webpage.

What I am missing here?

Comment: what is inside Environment.Hostname[domain] ?

Answer (score 0):

In your case if the gotourl is blank then you would get blank page.

This is what I usually do:

```
IWebDriver driver;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
String baseURL = "http://localhost";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/somepage.aspx");
```

Comment: The URL is built correctly as the test works fine in IE. I dont know what I am missing with Firefox driver.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen with non compatible versions of Firefox. Make sure you turn off auto-update in the Firefox settings to avoid the latest version being installed by default.

To test that it is Firefox at fault change your WebDriver to another driver such as InternetExplorerDriver, ChromeDriver or SafariDriver.

Until Web Driver is supported, you can always downgrade your version of Firefox. Hope this helps.